# Resizing image in php after file_get_contents

Tags: php, image, url, upload, file-get-contents

Can anybody tell me how I can solve the following issue:

```
include('php/resizeImage.php');

if($_POST['uploadlink']){
    $url = $_POST['uploadlink'];
    $urlImage = file_get_contents($url);

    if ($_POST['filename']){
        $filename = $_POST['filename'].".jpg";
    } else {
        $urlinfo = parse_url($url);
        $filename = basename($urlinfo['path']);
    }

    $image = new ResizeImage();
    $image->load($filename);
    $image->resizeToWidth(300);
    $image->save($filename);

    file_put_contents("images/upload/".$filename, $urlImage);

  }
```

After I have received the image data from file_get_contents from a URL I want to resize it through my resizeImage script which takes the filename of the image as a parameter.

Edit: ResizeImage function load and resizeToWidth:

```
function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }

function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
```

I have no trouble doing it when the user selects a local image through input type='file'.

```
    if (isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"])){
        $ufilename = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
        $ufiletmpname = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];

        $image = new ResizeImage();
        $image->load($ufiletmpname);
        $image->resizeToWidth(300);
        $image->save($ufiletmpname);
}
```

Another problem:
I forward the name of the user to my script because I want to create an individual folder for each user, so they only can see their own uploaded images.

```
$admin = $_GET['admin'];
file_put_contents("images/upload/".$admin."/".$filename, $urlImage);
```

Why is this not working for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easy.
Just alter the code of whatever *yours* ResizeImage class to make it able to operate the image binary contents in addition to filename.

Your second question is quite simple too.
Setup your PHP installation to make it display errors on the screen (for the development server, of course!) and you will see the exact answer to your question, "Why is this not working for me?".

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

usually helps.
(also be sure your code do not do any HTTP redirects which may conceal the error messages from you)

Comment: Thank you. Haven't written the resizeImage class myself but I will try.

Answer (score 1):

What's ResizeImage?

If it were me, I'd do:

```
$data = file_get_contents($name);

$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

// resize the image
```

Comment: I will try that. Thanks. ResizeImage is "my own" class. I have inserted the the load and resizeToWidth function in the original msg

Comment: Is doesn't work. I can resize the image after having created imagecreatefromstring but then I can't use file_put_contents with the $image as a parameter.

Comment: You don't have to use `file_put_contents()`. Use `imagepng($image, $filename);` instead. You also should read the PHP docs on this extension...

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the ResizeImage is your own class, or something you downloaded from the net. To help you, we need to see it.

For the second part, file_put_contents won't create directories to you, to do that, you need to use the mkdir function.

Comment: Okay, but I have already tried to pre-create a folder on the server with the exact same name as $admin, and that didn't work either

Comment: Tried the mkdir. It doesn't even create the folder. Can it be some restrictions on the FTP?

Comment: then it's probably a permission problem - the user of your php script (web server) can't write the target directory. It has nothing to do with the ftp protocol/server. You should change the folder's permissions.